# Trying to use try and catch for a condition

Tags: javascript

I've got a method for check a version. Now, if the file Version doen't exist, I want display this error with a try and catch

I'm trying to do this but don't know if it is good

```
  public checkVersionFile(): any {
    const contentVersion = fs.readFileSync( "Version", 'utf8')

    try{
        if(contentVersion.endsWith('-SNAPSHOT')){
            let match = /^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)-(\d+)-(SNAPSHOT)$/.exec(contentVersion);
            const version =  (parseInt(match[1])) + '.' + (parseInt(match[2])) + '.' + (parseInt(match[3])) + '-' + (parseInt(match[4]));
            return version
        }
        else {
            logger.error("Cannot be released without SNAPSHOT inside Version file in components");
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        return Promise.reject("file Version doesn't exist");
    }

}
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: `Promise.reject`? is that function asynchronous?

Comment: Yes it's asynchronous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File read operation is not inside of `try/catch` block so this error couldn't be caught.

```
  public checkVersionFile(): any {


    try {
        const contentVersion = fs.readFileSync( "Version", 'utf8')

        if(contentVersion.endsWith('-SNAPSHOT')){
            let match = /^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)-(\d+)-(SNAPSHOT)$/.exec(contentVersion);
            const version =  (parseInt(match[1])) + '.' + (parseInt(match[2])) + '.' + (parseInt(match[3])) + '-' + (parseInt(match[4]));
            return version
        }
        else {
            logger.error("Cannot be released without SNAPSHOT inside Version file in components");
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        return Promise.reject("file Version doesn't exist");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to reject a `Promise` but your method is not returning a `Promise`.

You need to either [throw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) an [error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error)

```
public checkVersionFile(): any {
    const contentVersion = fs.readFileSync( "Version", 'utf8')

    try{
        if(contentVersion.endsWith('-SNAPSHOT')){
            let match = /^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)-(\d+)-(SNAPSHOT)$/.exec(contentVersion);
            const version =  (parseInt(match[1])) + '.' + (parseInt(match[2])) + '.' + (parseInt(match[3])) + '-' + (parseInt(match[4]));
            return version
        }
        else {
            logger.error("Cannot be released without SNAPSHOT inside Version file in components");
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        throw new Error("file Version doesn't exist");
    }

}
```

Or return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

```
public checkVersionFile(): any {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const contentVersion = fs.readFileSync( "Version", 'utf8')

        try{
            if(contentVersion.endsWith('-SNAPSHOT')){
                let match = /^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)-(\d+)-(SNAPSHOT)$/.exec(contentVersion);
                const version =  (parseInt(match[1])) + '.' + (parseInt(match[2])) + '.' + (parseInt(match[3])) + '-' + (parseInt(match[4]));
                resolve(version);
            }
            else {
                logger.error("Cannot be released without SNAPSHOT inside Version file in components");
                resolve();
            }
        }
        catch (err) {
            reject("file Version doesn't exist");
        }
    });
}
```